# Getting Week for a given number from a String of the form `SunMonTueWedThuFriSat`

Tags: java, string, integer

Ok, I am stumped here. I really looked into this and cant seem to find specifically what I am trying to do. I am two weeks into Java in school and new to programming so please pardon any errors I may make.

I am working on a string manipulation program and among other tasks in it I am to create a sting called names that holds `SunMonTueWedThuFriSat`, now I need to figure out how to grab and display in **JOptionPane** the 3 characters in that string that go with the numbers I am supposed to associate with them `(0=Sun, 1=Mon, etc.)` So if the user inputs 2 it should display Tue. I have a basic understanding on how to display those characters in a string, but for the life of me i cant seem to figure out how to associate those numbers with those characters. Every time I try to work something I keep getting errors and frustration.

Thanks for all your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use substring, since all the abbreviations are three characters.

```
String s = "SunMonTueWedThuFriSat";
```

Prompt the user to enter a number (0-6):

```
String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a number (0-6)");
```

Now convert it to a number

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(in);
```

And select the right portion of the string:

```
String day = s.substring(choice*3, choice*3+3);
```

Now just show this day in a JOptionPane:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Information", "You chose: " + day, 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
```

Comment: I almost got it but if I declare the int choice as 2 it just keeps giving me the same output, would i leave that part blank if i want the user to choose the day and to have it displayed for them?

Comment: I updated my answer to use a JOptionPane input dialog to prompt the user for a choice.

Comment: That did it! thank you so much, now i just gotta look over everything and try to understand what happened. Im so glad I took up programming knowing there are great people out there to help and are interested in the same things i am. :)

Comment: Of course. Its a great community. The key here is the substring line. Work through the math for all the choices. For example, if choice=2, substring(2*3, 2*3+3) is substring(6, 9) which returns the characters at index 6, 7, and 8 ("Tue").

Answer (score 1):

If the days of the week has to be in a single string, you can parse the string for each 3 character substring, and store then in an ArrayList.  Then, the provided number will match the index of the Day of the Week in the List.

Comment: Ie, using String.substring in a loop until you've reached the end of the string being parsed.  In the loop, add the substring to the ArrayList<String>.  Then, the input number is the index to use when pulling the Day from the List.

Comment: Although, it seems a bit arbitrary to start with a single string, when you could just start with the List...

Comment: ok, ill research how to parse things and making an arraylist, thank you!

Comment: thats what i thought, i looked over the directions a bunch and she wants it just like that i guess to teach good string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Check [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

For example:

```
HashMap<int, String> aWeekMap = new HashMap();
aWeekMap.put(0, "Mon");
aWeekMap.put(1, "Tue");

System.out.println(aWeekMap.get(0)); // prints Mon.
```

In memory you can visualize as following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an array of string, it will be easier:

```
String[] names = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};

int input = 2;

System.out.println("The day is " + names[input]);
```

Comment: so, if they enter any number it will display the correct day? Also, will the last part of the code look the same in JOptionPane? Instead of System.out.println I could use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The day is" + [input]); ?

Comment: yes you were almost right, but you need to use `names[input]` instead of just `[input]`

Comment: ok, do i make seperate integers for all the different inputs for the different days, i ran the program and it always gives me the default. I hope i make sense. I want it to change if the user changes the day JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your phone number is: " + phone+
    "\nToday is: " + names[input] +

Comment: No you just make that array `names` as I have made and store the user input in some variable say `abc` is my variable for use input and then use that variable like `names[abc]`

Answer (score 0):

use the follwing code

```
private ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
arr.Add(0,names.subString(0,2);
arr.Add(0,names.subString(3,5);
arr.Add(0,names.subString(6,8);
arr.Add(0,names.subString(9,11);
arr.Add(0,names.subString(12,14);
arr.Add(0,names.subString(15,17);
arr.Add(0,names.subString(18,20);
```

and

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a name", "Example 1",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, arr);
```